# How I can commit and push configurations to remote git with hawtio?

Tags: hawtio

how I can commit and push changes to my remote git, which I make with the Hawtio git/wiki plugin?

I've looked at the https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-camel-wiki project but I can't find any config params for user credentials.
Furthermore, I can't find any commit/push button in the gui.

For notice, I changed the Hawtio version to 1.4.51 in the hawtio-camel-wiki project, forked the https://github.com/gigagon/hawtio-camel-wiki-config and changed the configuration in blueprint.properties.

After that, I tried to find some hints in the code of Hawtio git, but i can't find anything. Is commit/push feature not supported in non fabric8/openshift environments?

That would be great, if you could help me.